# Why do I get an error when declaring a constraint programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am declaring a constraint inside a `UIViewController` class called `Home`. Here's what the code looks like:

```
class Home: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonUpgrade: UIButton!

var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: buttonUpgrade, 
attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
toItem: self.view, 
attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
multiplier: 1, 
constant: 500)

...
}
```

However, I get this error: `Home.type does not have a member named buttonUpgrade`. Why?

You can download the project from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7avclri0ijw3pd/DemoConstraints.zip?dl=0.

Comment: The code needs to be inside a method. Did you not notice that you have the same code in viewDidLoad, and that one doesn't give you an error?

Comment: Yes, I did notice it. Thank you for commenting. It would be VERY useful if I could just set up a global variable for the `NSLayoutConstraint` variable `var constraint` to avoid any errors such as `Unable to simultaneously  satisfy constraints`. In fact, if I try to declare another time `var constraint` and assign to its `constant` a new value I receive that error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can create a property at the top of the file for the constraint, var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint! . Then when you create the constraint in viewDidLoad (or anywhere else), just use self.constraint = ... (actually, you don't even need the "self" in Swift, but I still like to use it).

Comment: The problem is that the initialization of `constraint` depends on other properties of the same class. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582853/type-does-not-have-a-member, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855137/viewcontrol-type-does-not-have-a-member-named (with different solutions).

Comment: @rdelmar That's a nice idea! Thank you. But how do I tell the compiler that constraint   has `attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom`?

Comment: Looking at this question that I posted some years ago makes me cringe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, you can't write such code outside a function. But what you can do is declaring your variable global(outside a function) like that:

```
var constraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then you can initialize it in for example your `viewDidLoad`-method which will be called once:

```
constraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: buttonUpgrade, 
attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
toItem: self.view, 
attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
multiplier: 1, 
constant: 500)
```

After you did that, you can access the constraint variable from everywhere in your class. Just make sure that the variable is filled before using it.